# How to install and configure kube-state-metrics for external prometheus serverto monitor kubernetes

Tags: prometheus, kube-state-metrics

How to install and configure kube-state-metrics to monitor kubernetes on external/separate/centralized prometheus server.

I came across some articles that pointed me to kube-state-metrics but am not sure where i need to run the kube-state-metrics

I have 2 kubernetes cluster and i want to monitor both the kubernetes cluster metrics on Prometheus and grafana(for visualization.
How can this be achieve using one prometheus server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics) is a simple service that listens to the `Kubernetes API server` and generates metrics about the state of the objects.

Here you will find a list of yamls: [link](https://github.com/kamolhasan/K8s-Monitoring-Pipeline/tree/master/examples/kube-state-metrics)

It contains:

1. **Deployment**: Where container fetches `image: quay.io/coreos/kube-state-metrics:v1.6.0`
2. **Service account**: Service account of deployment object
3. **Role and RoleBinding**: RBAC cluster role and role binding for the service account
4. **Service**: k8s service that listen to the pods under deployments

So when you have all these set up. You are ready to go. Now you configure your prometheus to scrape metrics from the k8s Service you created in no. 4.

[Here](https://gardener.cloud/050-tutorials/content/howto/service-access/) you will find how to generate `address` for the k8s service.

Configure prometheus:

```sh
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'kube-state-metrics'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['address'] //address of the k8s service
```

Comment: Hi Kamol Hasan, Thanks for the reply, it will be helpful if you can point me to the prometheus configuration.which i can use to integrate with kubernetes Service(Kube-state-metrics).

Comment: Hi @Kamol Hasan Thanks for the reply and it is working fine